# Error: File "./assets/controllers.json" could not be found

Tags: node.js, symfony, webpack, manifest

After building a Symphony project on my main Mac, I wanted to run it on my MacBook.

Here is the steps I made :

- clone GitHub repo
- cd my project
- composer install
- npm install
- npm run watch

I wanted to `npm run watch` to create the `manifest.json` file.

Here is the error I get after running `npm run watch` :

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
johanbrazillier@johans-macbook-air laboutiquefr % yarn build
yarn run v1.22.18
$ encore production --progress
Running webpack ...

  Error: File "./assets/controllers.json" could not be found.
  
  - WebpackConfig.js:674 WebpackConfig.enableStimulusBridge
    [laboutiquefr]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/WebpackConfig.js:674:19
  
  - index.js:1030 Encore.enableStimulusBridge
    [laboutiquefr]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/index.js:1030:23
  
  - EncoreProxy.js:51 Proxy.minDistance
    [laboutiquefr]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/EncoreProxy.js:51:53
  
  - webpack.config.js:26 Object.<anonymous>
    /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laboutiquefr/webpack.config.js:26:6
  
  - loader:1105 Module._compile
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14
  
  - loader:1159 Module._extensions..js
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10
  
  - loader:981 Module.load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32
  
  - loader:827 Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12
  
  - loader:1005 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19
  
  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18
  

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Without this file, I can't run my project.

Any idea why I have this error ?

PS : I have Node, Git, Xcode, Symphony CLI, etc... installed and up to date.

Comment: Avez vous quelque chose quand vous effectuez la commande suivante `composer recipes -o` ?

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz oh it works now ! Merciiiii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vinceAmstoutz suggested, `composer recipes -o` solved the problem.

Thank you !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).